# Faster way to create objects from array using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `CSV` list of values which I am converting into a `User` object.
I have done this via a foreach loop but wonder if there's a way of doing this via `LINQ` in a more efficient manner?
I've tried a combination of using `Select` and `Where` but cannot seem to find a method specific to my case.

**User.cs:**

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Current way of doing it:**

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Select(x => x.Split(';'));

var users = new List<User>();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        FirstName = line[0],
        LastName = line[1],
        Password = line[2]
    };

    users.Append(user);
}
```

Comment: Has this code proven to be a bottleneck? Why do you want it to perform better, and what have you tried?

Comment: You can use LiNQ's `Select` function: `var users = lines.Select(line => new User { FirstName = line[0], LastName = line[1], Password = line[2] });`

Comment: I would assume that this code is IO bound and not CPU bound. One small optimization is that you can initialize `users` to the length of `lines` to avoid resizing your list.

Comment: Can you describe what kind of efficency you expect. Beautifull code or code which runs fast?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about :

```
var users = lines.Select(line=>new User
        {
            FirstName = line[0],
            LastName = line[1],
            Password = line[2]
        }).ToList();
```

The last ToList is optional whether you want to collect immediatly or not.

You can even in one step like:

```
var users = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Select(x=>
{ 
    var line = x.Split(';');
    return new User
        {
            FirstName = line[0],
            LastName = line[1],
            Password = line[2]
        };
}).ToList();
```

Edit:
To clarify I decompose :

```
var users = File.ReadAllLines("filepath").Select(BuildFromLine).ToList();
```

The select takes as a parameter a Function with a string as input and whatever as output (here a user). Then I have a function to build my users.
In the above notation I transformed the function in an anonymous lambda.
Note that for clarity I kept the name x for the parameter of the function but in the real world I would have renamed it to reflect what it really is (x becomes line and line becomes tokens).

```
public static User BuildFromLine(string x)
{
    var line = x.Split(';');
    return new User
    {
        FirstName = line[0],
        LastName = line[1],
        Password = line[2]
    };
}
```

Comment: But is this faster?

Comment: @CodeCaster Is this the intention? He wants it to be efficient. This can be : cpu efficient, memory efficient or just code which looks good. As he mentionned he tried select and where, I understood he just wanted code to be more elegant. Downgrading my answer is not justified until stzvggmd clarifies his position.

Answer (score 0):

You could to it entirely with LINQ:

```
var users = File.ReadAllLines(path)
  .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
  .Select(splitLine => new User { FirstName = splitLine[0], LastName = splitLine[1], Password = splitLine[2] })
  .ToArray();
```